# Create a custom \section

Tags: sectioning

I am using the following code for the sections of my document. I would like that the thin line under `SECTION` would stop at three quarter of `\textwidth` instead of cover the total width. How can I do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl} % Paper options using the scrartcl class

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \section's\usepackage{url}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Section formatting

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a well-known fact, that `scrartcl` and `titlesec` do not work well together ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, final]{scrartcl} % Paper options using the scrartcl class   
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \section's\usepackage{url}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\rule{.75\linewidth}{1pt}] % Section formatting
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```